# How to 'pivot' these 3 entries into a single row? ( tied together by the same composite key)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the following sample data (3 tables)

I have a 'main' driver table called **CASE**

```
CASE_ID      CASE_NAME        CASE_DATE
   1         Test1            01-JAN-18
   2         Test2            02-JAN-18
   3         Test1 p2         03-JAN-18
   4         Test2 p2         03-JAN-18
```

I have a rel_table called **CASE_VAL_REL**

```
CASE_VAL_ID       CASE_ID       VAL_ID          CASE_VAL_TYPE
    1               1             1             Weight
    2               3             2             Height
    3               3             3             Age
    4               2             4             Weight
    5               4             5             Height
    6               4             6             Age
```

And lastly I have a table that needs to be joined to the REL table called **VAL**

```
VAL_ID      VAL       TIMESTAMP      PERSON_NAME      GENDER
  1         150       06-FEB-19      Matt             Male
  2         62        06-FEB-19      Matt             Male
  3         25        06-FEB-19      Matt             Male
  4         100       06-FEB-19      Pauline          Female
  5         70        06-FEB-19      Pauline          Female
  6         22        06-FEB-19      Pauline          Female
```

I need a result set/table that looks like the following (it cannot be joined by the case_id, since they opened two separate cases to derive the needed information. Instead we may need to join on a 'composite key' of some sorts. Below is my desired result set:

```
 PERSON_NAME    GENDER     AGE      WEIGHT    HEIGHT
  Matt          Male       25       150       62
  Pauline       Female     22       100       70
```

Below is my attempt but it is not quite working like I want it to (at least for a larger data set)

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN CASE_VAL_TYPE = 'Weight'
            THEN VAL
             END)   as             Weight
     , MAX(CASE WHEN CASE_VAL_TYPE = 'Height'
            THEN VAL
             END)   as             Height
     , MAX(CASE WHEN CASE_VAL_TYPE = 'Age'
            THEN VAL
             END)   as             Age
     , PERSON_NAME
     , GENDER
   FROM CASE C
   JOIN CASE_VAL_REL CVR on C.CASE_ID = CVR.CASE_ID
   JOIN VAL V on CVR.VAL_ID = V.VAL_ID
  GROUP BY PERSON_NAME, GENDER;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your way is good, and works properly I think.

Comment: thank you. I am returning some weird results, I will have to investigate further :)

Comment: you're welcome. Have a look at this demo link please : https://rextester.com/REXGT74563

Comment: "Below is my attempt but it is not quite working like I want it to (at least for a larger data set)" As in performance wise? Because your query should give the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took VAL_ID as sequence number and VAL ordered in Weight,Height and Age, not sure is my interpretation correct  to derive the expected result from final table 'VAL' only to avoid joins to other tables.

```
 create table VAL
    (VAL_ID NUMBER,
    VAL   NUMBER,
    TIMESTAMP DATE,
    PERSON_NAME varchar2(20),
    GENDER   varchar2(10));

    insert into VAL values(1,150,'06-FEB-19','Matt','Male');
    insert into VAL values(2,62,'06-FEB-19','Matt','Male');
    insert into VAL values(3,25,'06-FEB-19','Matt','Male');
    insert into VAL values(4,100,'06-FEB-19','Pauline','Female');
    insert into VAL values(5,70,'06-FEB-19','Pauline','Female');
    insert into VAL values(6,22,'06-FEB-19','Pauline','Female');


    select PERSON_NAME,GENDER,
          max(case when mod(VAL_ID,3)=1 then VAL end) "WEIGHT",
          max(case when mod(VAL_ID,3)=2 then VAL end) "HEIGHT",
          max(case when mod(VAL_ID,3)=0 then VAL end) "AGE"
    from VAL
    group by PERSON_NAME,GENDER;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you of change the table mane case  in cases for avoid conflie with   the case when sintax
and starting  form VAL use a left join for CASES

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN CVR.CASE_VAL_TYPE = 'Weight'
            THEN V.VAL
             END)   as             Weight
     , MAX(CASE WHEN CVR.CASE_VAL_TYPE = 'Height'
            THEN V.VAL
             END)   as             Height
     , MAX(CASE WHEN CVR.CASE_VAL_TYPE = 'Age'
            THEN V.VAL
             END)   as             Age
     , V.PERSON_NAME
     , V.GENDER
   FROM VAL V 
   INNER JOIN CASE_VAL_REL CVR on CVR.VAL_ID = V.VAL_ID 
   LEFT JOIN  CASES C on C.CASE_ID = CVR.CASE_ID
   GROUP BY PERSON_NAME, GENDER;
```

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the tables t1, t2, and t3.  Looking at the data I then dropped t1 from the solution as you seem to want one row per person so all target data is in t2 and t3.  I selected the name, gender and SUM( case when case_val_type = 'X' then val else 0) where X is each possible type FROM ( WITH people as (select distinct person_name from t3) select people.person_name, t3.gender, t2.case_val_type, t3.val from people join t3 on t3.person_name = people.person_name  join t2 on t2.val_id = t3.val_id  ) iq group by iq.person_name, iq.gender and the result is your two line target.  -- Forgive my not formatting this but I have yet to find the formatting instructions.